# I made this and my bot loops the "else" function. I'm confused cuz I don't think I have any intentions to make a looping function

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I made a bot with purpose to manage discord roles and here's my code briefly

```
bot.on('message', (message) => {

    const parts = message.content.split(' ');

        if (parts[0] == 'Platform' || 'platform') {

            if (parts[1] == 'iOS') {
                message.channel.send(`thx, ${message.author}`)
                message.member.roles.add(iOS); 
            } 
           else {
                message.channel.send(`nooo`)
            }

        }
}
```

Why my else command keeps going over and over? How am I supposed to do in order to stop it?

Comment: Because `parts[0] == 'Platform' || 'platform'` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: what should I do to make it do what I think it does?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should read:

```
if (parts[0] == 'Platform' || parts[0] == 'platform') {
```

Comment: I just gave you the corrected code to use. Use my code in place of yours.